# Joomla isset($data) prepare form why?

Tags: php, joomla, isset

It's not really a problem but I need to know why this comportement.

```
Function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)

        $data = (object) $data;

    if(isset($data->folder) && $data->folder != 'jfcore' 
        || isset($data->name) && $data->name == 'plg_jfcore_jfcore' 
        || isset($data->element) && $data->element == "jfcore" && in_array($data->folder, $this->cores) 
        || isset($data->element) && $data->element == "jfcore" && in_array($data->folder, $this->third_cores))
        return;
```

Si if I don't put **$data = (object) $data;** It will show me this error **Trying to get property of non-object** but it's already an object.

After if I don't put **isset($data->name)** error : **Undefined property: stdClass::$name**

My new function

```
        if(is_array($data))return true;
    $data = (object) $data;

    if(isset($data->folder) && $data->folder != 'jfcore' 
        || isset($data->name) && $data->name == 'plg_jfcore_jfcore' 
        || isset($data->element) && isset($data->folder) && $data->element == "jfcore" && in_array($data->folder, $this->cores) 
        || isset($data->element) && isset($data->folder) && $data->element == "jfcore" && in_array($data->folder, $this->third_cores)
        )
    return true;
```

Ou

```
        // We don't need system log for these plugins
    if(isset($data->folder) && $data->folder != 'jfcore' 
        || isset($data->name) && $data->name == 'plg_jfcore_jfcore' 
        || isset($data->element) && $data->element == "jfcore" && isset($data->folder) && in_array($data->folder, $this->cores) 
        || isset($data->element) && $data->element == "jfcore" && isset($data->folder) && in_array($data->folder, $this->third_cores)
        || empty((array)$data)
        )
        return;
```

For return or return true it's depend in what function you are.

Comment: are you sure that `$data` is already an object? what is the result of `gettype($data)`?

Comment: probably $data is an array, so you must cast to object, and isset is required as clearly not all properties are guaranteed to be defined

Comment: What do you get if you put `var_dump($data);` at the start of the function?

Comment: No, 100% sure it's a object and i tried gettype = object.

Comment: $data is almost always an array though the docblocks do say mixed in some places.

Comment: He show me everytime JObject but I found when I submit the form no $data and it's an array.